# How do I remove vertical line from my blog?

Tags: html, blogger

I want to use classic theme but it displays a vertical line. Any help how I can remove the line ? site : https://ora-err.blogspot.com

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the background in the div with id = "main3".

Having a good day